# hide all duplicate columns in excel

Tags: vba, excel

**How can I hide all duplicate columns if text in row 8 is the same.**

I have a drop down of materials. Multiple columns with the same number are used for a BOM. Would like to show only unique values from row 8 with a macro but also have an unhide all columns with another macro.

Im sure this is pretty simple but not sure where to start.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you read **[what topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** and **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim last_col, col, a As Integer
Dim unique_materials(100), material As String


Sub show_all_columns()
    last_col = Range("XFD8").End(xlToLeft).Column
    For col = 1 To last_col
        Columns(col).Hidden = False
    Next col
End Sub

Sub hide_duplicates()
    Erase unique_materials
    last_col = Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Column
    a = 0
    For col = 1 To last_col
        material = Cells(8, col)
        If UBound(Filter(unique_materials, material)) > -1 Then
            Columns(col).Hidden = True
        Else
            unique_materials(a) = material
            a = a + 1
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```